# Unable to validate optional FormControl in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Reactive Form in my Angular project that looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="indirizzoForm" (ngSubmit)="indirizzoSubmit(stepper)">
          <h4>Indirizzo di consegna</h4>
          <hr />
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label
                >Nome <span class="text-muted">(sul campanello)</span></label
              >
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                required
                formControlName="nome"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label
                >Cognome <span class="text-muted">(sul campanello)</span></label
              >
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                required
                formControlName="cognome"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Indirizzo</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              required
              formControlName="indirizzo"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label
              >Informazioni aggiuntive
              <span class="text-muted">(facoltativo)</span></label
            >
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              required
              formControlName="info"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label>Cap</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                required
                formControlName="cap"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label>Città</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                required
                formControlName="citta"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quando </label>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                id="radioOra"
                value=""
                (click)="adesso()"
                [checked]="adessoCheck"
                name="quando"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="radioOra">
                Adesso <span class="text-muted">(Arrivo tra 20-40 min)</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                id="radioProgramma"
                value=""
                [checked]="programmaCheck"
                (click)="programma($event, programmaModal)"
                name="quando"
              />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="radioProgramma">
                Programma
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            [disabled]="!indirizzoForm.valid"
          >
            Procedi
          </button>
          <p>{{ indirizzoForm.status }}</p>
        </form>
```

In the following form all controls are required instead of **info** that should be optional so if there is no data the form should be anyway submitted with info set as empty string.

My typescript code looks like this:

```
  indirizzoForm = new FormGroup({
    nome: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    cognome: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    indirizzo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    info: new FormControl(''),
    cap: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    citta: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    quando: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
```

But even if no Validators is attached to info the form results invalid if info is empty...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you add required in the info box, Info is an optional field right

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label
          >Informazioni aggiuntive
          <span class="text-muted">(facoltativo)</span></label
        >
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          required
          formControlName="info"
        />
      </div>
```

Please remove required from info field

Comment: please accept this answer, if this fixed your problem, thank you